# Custom navigation in Halogy CMS

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, halogy

Can someone tell me how to use custom navigation in Halogy CMS?

I modded the permissions directly in the DB, now I can access /admin/pages/navigation
But nothing is showing up in the Admin panel or up front...

Comment: can you clearly define what you want?

Comment: There is an option to add more navigatable menu's, but how?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem. i suggest you create pages and set their status to publish and refresh the front and you will see the navigation item in the list with Home , Blog , Shop , Admin.